# Is it bad practise to apply a 'hidden' class to components, instead of using *ngIf to hide them? - Angular

Tags: angular

Imagine I have two components, with one being hidden when the other one is shown, like this:

```
<div>
  <componentOne *ngIf="showComponentOne"></componentOne>
  <componentTwo *ngIf="!showComponentOne"></componentTwo>
</div>
```

Now `componentOne` includes a decently large `<img>` picture, which is being loaded every time it gets initialized. When the component is activated, for a short time frame the images alt-attribute is shown until the image is loaded. Because that is pretty noticeable, I was wondering if I could solve it like this:

```
<div>
  <componentOne [ngClass]="showComponentOne ? '' : 'hidden'"></componentOne>
  <componentTwo *ngIf="!showComponentOne"></componentTwo>
</div>
```

Would this be considered bad practice, because the component doesn't get removed from the DOM when it's not used? Or is it fine if `componentOne` is pretty small? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's necessarily bad practise; I think it's a case of considering which approach is best suited to your interface and the circumstances under which the image will be displayed.

If for example you had a table with 100 rows, each of which had an image which would be revealed one at a time on mouseover, *ngIf would (clearly, I think) be the best solution, partly down to memory consumption as per [Argo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4881398/argo) point below.

But in this case where you have two components and particularly if users will be switching between them more than once, I think 'hiding' (by whatever means) them rather than removing from the DOM completely is sensible.

If you are switching between displaying either component 1 or component 2, I would suggest using a consistent approach, I.e. hide them both, or use ngIf to remove them from the DOM, rather than 'hiding' one and using ngIf on the other, though again this is subject to your judgement on the best approach for your application.

Comment: Thanks for your thought out response, that makes a lot of sense. I'll apply your approach and check the memory consumption differences.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is recommended to not apply hidden class. Reason being, the particular html tag would be processed which will consume memory.

Suppose you use hidden inside a child component tag from a parent tag, though the html would not be visible but your component would be loaded. And suppose your component has a lot of api calls, then it would be calling those api even though they are not used anywhere

Also I remember reading in few places for SEO tips to not use, though I couldn't find a reliable source to back it now.

Comment: Thanks for your input. In this case, the component doesn't do a lot of logic and no api calls at all, so applying a hidden class might not be an issue. Good call on the SEO though, I'll look into it!

Answer (score 1):

ngIf destoyes the component and renders it again whereas hidden siimply hides it. It depends on your application. If you need to construct the component when condition changes - use ngIf. If you need to preload it and show it by demand - use hidden...

Furthermore if you want to refer to refer to component in template via ViewChild you can't use ngIf. Because its not rendered yet... In this case  - you need to use hidden.

Just apply hidden. Its not gonna destroy the component in DOM, but gonna hide it.

```
<componentOne [hidden]="showComponentOne ? true : false"></componentOne>
```

Certainly if showComponentOne property is boolean is looks as

```
<componentOne [hidden]="showComponentOne"></componentOne>
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as applying a hidden-class (except that it's cleaner)? The component is still attached to the DOM - is that okay? Thanks for your response!

Comment: Once again - it depends on your application. If you need to remove a component from DOM - use ngIf. If you want to hide it - use hidden. Keep in mind that after ngIf  changes destroyed and constructed again... In other words immagine the component which loads data from the server and you just want to conditionally hide it - use hidden... Otherwise if you want to renew its data - use ngIf

Answer (score 1):

I Dont think it is a bad practice as long as you understand different scnerio and it also depends on specific use case:

**I would say : you should never use `hidden` class if :**

1.It is the initial landing page of website because it will decrease performance

2.If its a huge page and you dont need it everywhere

**But  `ng-if` also have Pitfalls like these:**

1.The component and directives in the element that’s being removed and added again will actually be recreated and so their initialization logic will run again. This is in contrast to `hidden` where things are always there in memory, and so are only initialized once. You need to make sure your code handles being rerun properly.

2.Sometimes initialization is more expensive than keeping things around.

3.And you have to use `hidden` when you have to append some elements to parent element at runtime like this: `element.appendChild(aChild);`